# How to round down if the result exceeds dollar amount allowed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am a teacher currently assigned to computer class. I'm pretty good, but I'm stuck on this. My students are doing a stock market project and I want excel to calculate how many shares per stock they can purchase with $1,000.

For example, AAPL is $545 so 1000/545 is 1.8. The answer should be 1 share, but excel rounds up to 2.

How can I set this to only use whole numbers but round down if they exceed the budget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`ROUNDDOWN`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rounddown-HP005209241.aspx) will do that for you.

```
ROUNDDOWN(number,num_digits)
```

So if `A1` is 1000 and `B1` is 545, you could use the following formula to get the answer.

```
=ROUNDDOWN(SUM(A1/B1),0)
```

This returns `1` as an answer.

Comment: Your welcome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

The [`FLOOR`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/floor-HP005209094.aspx) function will always round down.

Just for good measure, here is a summary of the rounding functions.  The primary difference between similar functions being how negative numbers are handled.

- `ROUND` - Uses normal rounding rules.  Digits 0-4 round towards zero, 5-9 round away from zero.
- `ROUNDUP` - Always rounds away from zero.  5.5 rounds to 6 and -5.5 rounds to -6.
- `ROUNDDOWN` - Always rounds towards zero.  5.5 rounds 5 to 5 and -5.5 rounds to -5.
- `CEILING` - Always rounds towards positive infinity.  5.5 rounds to 6 and -5.5 rounds to -5.
- `FLOOR` - Always rounds towards negative infinity.  5.5 rounds to 5 and -5.5 rounds to -6.